# Unexpected eta expansion in constant definition

Tags: coq, universe

Start from this example in *section 2.1.14: Polymorphic Universes* in Coq's reference maunual (slightly modified):

```
Definition id (A : Type) (a : A) := a.

Set Printing Universes.
Fail Definition selfid := id _ id.
  (*
    The command has indeed failed with message:
    The term "id" has type "forall A : Type@{id.u0}, A -> A" while it is expected
    to have type "?A" (unable to find a well-typed instantiation for "?A": cannot 
    ensure that "Type@{id.u0+1}" is a subtype of "Type@{id.u0}").
  *)
```

Consider a variant to the failed definition

```
Definition selfid := id (forall A : Type, A -> A) id.
```

Unexpectedly, this command does not fail. Moreover, it seems that Coq automatically $\eta$-expanded the second `id` in the definition of `selfid`:

```
Set Printing Universes.
Print selfid.
  (*
    selfid = id (forall A : Type@{selfid.u0}, A -> A) (fun A : Type@{selfid.u0} => id A)
      : forall A : Type@{selfid.u0}, A -> A
    (* {selfid.u0} |= selfid.u0 < id.u0 *)
  *)
```

This $\eta$-conversion does make the definition of `selfid` valid. However, why will Coq automatically conduct this expansion? Moreover, why Coq won't do this in the first (failed) definition of `selfid`?

Comment: Intriguing.  I would guess it has something to do with the explicit `Type` in the second `selfid` which gives it another universe parameter.  Maybe the eta-expansion happens during checking the second `id` against the supplied type `forall A : Type, A -> A`, which doesn't happen in the first case since the known type of `id` can be synthesized and equated to the implicit argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike Shulman got it right: this is a tricky question of how Coq solves unification problems. In short, in the first definition Coq takes the heuristic solution of letting your hole be unified with `forall A : Type@{id.u0}, A -> A`, which causes universe issues down the road, while in the second case the unification problem is solved by triggering the η-expansion that puzzles you, which is needed because cumulativity is equivariant rather than contravariant on the domains of product types. Let me try and give a more precise idea of what happens.

---

In the first definition, Coq generates a metavariable, called `?A` for the hole. It then starts by inferring a type for `id ?A`, which is `?A -> ?A` (learning along the way that we must have `?A : Type@{id.u0}`. Now to type-check `id ?A id`, it first infers a type for `id`, which is `forall A : Type@{id.u0}, A -> A`. Finally, this inferred type is compared with the domain of the type of `id ?A`, namely `?A`, for *cumulativity*, ie the problem is

```
(forall A : Type@{id.u0}, A -> A) <= ?A
```

The unification heuristics in such a setting give the "easy" answer to let `?A` be `forall A : Type@{id.u0}, A -> A`. Sadly, this is not a good solution here, as it leads you to universe inconsistencies in the elaborated term: recall we must have `?A : Type@{id.u0}` for `id ?A` to type-check, but the type of `forall A : Type@{id.u0}, A -> A` is `Type@{id.u0+1}`, which is what the type-checker complains about.

---

In the second definition, on the contrary, since you write `Type` a new, fresh level `selfid.u0` is first generated. As before, the type-checking of `id (forall A : Type@{selfid.u0}, A -> A)` happens first, returning the type `(forall A : Type@{selfid.u0}, A -> A) -> (forall A : Type@{selfid.u0}, A -> A)` (and learning along the way the constraint `selfid.u0 < id.u0`). Next, it infers a type for `id`, which is still `forall A : Type@{id.u0}, A -> A`. Finally, we get the cumulativity problem between the domain of `id (forall A : Type@{selfid.u0}, A -> A)` and this inferred type, which is now

```
(forall A : Type@{id.u0}, A -> A) <= (forall A : Type@{selfid.u0}, A -> A)
```

In Coq’s metatheory, cumulativity is *equivariant* on product domains, meaning here that the previous cumulativity can only hold if `Type@{selfid.u0}` and `Type@{id.u0}` are convertible, which in turn is only true if `selfid.u0 = id.u0`. But because of the constraint discovered earlier, this cannot hold, and so the problem does not have a solution. Note that if instead cumulativity were *contravariant* on product domains, since we know that `selfid.u0 < id.u0`, the cumulativity would hold. This contravariance, while quite common in subtyping for programming languages is not present in Coq because it is not easy to handle in set-theoretic models, which are the standard justification for cumulativity. Even though it is absent, it can still be mimicked by η-expanding functions: while `f : A' -> B` does have type `A -> B` only if `A` and `A'` are convertible, we still have that `fun x : A => f x : A -> B` whenever `A <= A'`. This is exactly what Coq does upon noticing that a cumulativity problem between products does not hold: it η-expands the function and tries again, which, in your case, succeeds.